# How do I change text in li without affecting siblings

Tags: jquery

Ok, guys, I spent the entire day yesterday googling and trying out different solutions but nothing has worked. I have a dynamically generated collapsible div which contains various things inside of it. My issue is arising with the text inside the `ul` I have inside the collapsible. An example of my structure is as follows.

```
<ul id="list-0">
   <li>
     <div id="div-00" class=".item">
       <span id="item-00">Item</span>
       <select id="slide-00" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
             <option value="on">Need</option>
             <option value="off">Done</option>                       
       </select>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div id="div-01" class=".item">
         <span id="item-01">Item</span>
         <select id="slide-01" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
             <option value="on">Need</option>
             <option value="off">Done</option>                       
         </select>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to change the text within the span. That's easy to do with a simple

```
  $("#item-00").text("whatevertext");
```

...and it works. But when I try to change the text of any following spans that text is applied to any previously clicked on spans....why does that happen?? Like if I go and change the text of the `id="#item-01"` span to **"apples"** after already changing the `id="#item-00"` span to **"bananas"** both spans will be changed to **"apples"**. This makes no sense to me and nothing I have tried has worked. If you need more of my code let me know.

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
     var div = $(this).attr("id"); 
     var split = div.split("-");
...more codings.... involving the opening of a popup to let user type in span text in input of id="thisothername"
     var name = $("#thisothername").attr("value");
     $("#" + "item" + "-" + split[1]).text(name);
});
```

I am currently using this to get the text from an input and apply it to the selected li > div > span  .... split[1] is an array index containing the parsed numeric value of the parent div id aka 00 or 01 which is then used to call the id of the child span and theoretically change ONLY that id's text aha.

Comment: It seems like two event handlers are being triggered, one for each item. Have you tried debugging your JavaScript code to find out what's happening? If you're using Chrome check [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function () {

  // .. some other stuff ...

  $(this)
    .find('span')
    .first()
    .text($("#thisothername").attr("value"));
});
```

Comment: Ok, just gave this a whirl. Again it changes the text of the span I click on, but all previously clicked on spans are also changed to the same text..

Comment: `.find('<element>')` saved my day. my `li` had 3 elements within it. I did `$(".contact-list ul li").eq(index).find(#id).text("..")` and replaced the text. Thank you @xat

Answer (score 0):

class name does not require the `.` in the markup

```
 <div id="div-00" class="item">
```

and now this should work

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
     var div = $(this).attr("id"); 
     var split = div.split("-");    
     //var name = $("#thisothername").attr("value"); //dont know what does it do
     $("#" + "item" + "-" + split[1]).text("some name");
});
```

or you can do it with the id splitting

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
         //var div = $(this).attr("id"); 
         //var split = div.split("-");    
         //var name = $("#thisothername").attr("value"); //dont know what does it do
         $("span",this).text("some name");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/utFmc/1/

Comment: "does not require" and shouldn't, not all browsers support that, and it interferes with multiclass!

Comment: @jackJoe while i was writing it was `doesn't` but now as you pointed out its `shouldn't`

Comment: That was a typo on my part. the "." does not exist in my actual markup. I just made an error and typing the post up, but I will give your solution a try here.

Comment: @jackJoe, so i played with the jsfiddle, and changing the text of the span works perfectly. I added a third li and after changing the text of the first span, changing the text of any subsequent spans doesn't propagate into the rest of the sibling spans. So why does your example work and mine doesn't?? confused.. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/utFmc/3/

Comment: ok, i removed the bit of code in there that called a popup to retrieve user input and instead used a simple prompt to gather the input and now it works...so i think that popup was causing that odd problem?? either way thanks again guys!